# Project Euler #6 Java Assistance

Tags: java

This seems simple enough but I'm getting an incorrect answer output by my code. Can someone hint at what I'm possibly missing here, or what I possibly might've made a mistake on without giving away any solutions?

The problem is to **find the difference between the sum of the squares of the first one hundred natural numbers and the square of the sum.**

My code:

```java
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
        //Sum of Squares = (2n^3 + 3n^2 + n)/6
        //Square of Sums = ((n^2 + n)/2)^2

        double sum_squares = ((2*Math.pow(100,3) + 3*Math.pow(100, 2) + 100)/6);
        double square_sums =  Math.pow(((Math.pow(100, 2) + 100)/2), 2);
        System.out.println((square_sums-sum_squares)+"\n");
    }
}
```

My output is 2.516415E7 which is not correct, even when I enter it without scientific notation.

Dear Stack Overflow -- what presumably simple thing am I missing here!

**EDIT: Peter de Rivaz solved my problem. What a silly mistake!**

Comment: You have 6 decimal places, but an exponent of 7.  Did you remember to put the zero on the end?

Comment: Haha you have humbled me, sir, this was my error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You must use exact, integer types like `int`, `long` or `BigInteger`. `float`/`double` will result in rounding errors. Besides - you are pretty close ;-).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I only used type double because of Math.pow() which in java docs says it needs double in the parameters. I'm going to just not use Math.pow() so I'll avoid using doubles. :)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is that you shouldn't be using doubles, but rather integer arithmetic.

Comment: I used doubles because I initially was planning on using Math.pow() which in the java docs has parameters of double. Thank you for your reply though I think I'm going to just not use Math.pow() which means I'll be using integers instead. :)